# Is ximagesrc capped at 60 frame/sec in GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am working on an application that needs to record my screen at X fps (the more, the better) I'm currenctly using GStreamer as it's a command line tool and it is very powerful.

My pipeline is :

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e ximagesrc ! \
    video/x-raw, framerate=120/1 ! videoconvert ! \
    jpegenc ! avimux ! filesink location=cap.avi
```

edit: if you want to run this, probably add a endx and endy parameters to ximagesrc (my video is usually 300x100)

This works with flaws : The codec is right, it's a 120 fps video, but it takes the 60 frames of the first and second video to build one sec at 120 fps.

I would like to know if my pipeline is erroneous or if ximagesrc is capped at 60 fps. If so, is there a way to by pass that, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`but it takes the 60 frames of the first and second video to build one sec at 120 fps.` I have difficult to understand that sentence.

Anyway. By default the Linux desktop refreshed at 60 Hz. So if you capture at 120 Hz you will capture the same image from the desktop twice. If you really want to capture 120 Hz you need to find a way to run your desktop at 120 Hz.

Comment: Hey, my linux desktop refreshes at 144 Hz.
The idea of the sentence is that : 1st sec I capture 60 frames, 2nd, still 60 frames
But I encoded at 120 frames per second, and the muxer sees it misses frames and grabs everything it can to go at asked 120 fps (60 + 60 = 120)
Also I figured out that avimux is capping framerate at 60

So I changed the muxer to a flvmuxer that doesn't restrict the framerate and now it works :)